# MySql - Update multiple rows from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to Mysql PHP combination and I am trying to update a column for multiple rows of a table. My query is as below:

```
<?php
class Calculations
{
    
    public function calculate()
    {
                        
        //database credentials
        $host = "localhost";
        $db_name = "dbtest";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
         
        //connect to database
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
        
        
        //Query to generate check-in variables from table
        $sql = "SELECT id,progname,preval1,preval2  
        FROM table";      

        //Store result on $result variable
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $count=mysqli_affected_rows($result);
        
        //function to calculate value
        function calcval($preval1, $preval2)
                {

                try{
                    return round(1-($preval1/$preval2));
                }catch(\Exception $e){
                    return null;
                }
                
                }
    
        $i=0;
        //looping through every row of the result
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            //assign values to each variable from table
            $preval1 = $row["preval1"];
            $preval2 = $row["preval2"];
            $calcval_new = calcval($preval1, $preval2);
            
            //update calcval field in that row of the result
            $update_sql = "UPDATE table SET calcval= $calcval_new[$i]";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $update_sql)) {
              echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
              echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    
    }   
} 

$calculations = new Calculations();
print $calculations->calculate();
?>
```

In this query, I am calculating field calcval using preval1, preval2 and those 2 come from the table itself. My table data looks like below:

[image]

In this table, I want to update calcval by using preval1,preval2 for every row of the table. My query is calculating the values correctly. But I don't know to loop through every record and update the calcval against that record. Can anyone please help?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you really want to use preval1/preval2 NOT preval1/preval1.

```
UPDATE table
SET calcval=IF(0=COALESCE(preval2, 0), NULL,
      1-preval1/preval2);
```

Comment: Thx that was a typo. But my actual problem is not with the function. I am unable to loop through every row of the table and update the value. Array related problem :(